# get value from 2 differend for each ranges, in a filtered worksheet with hidden colums and rows

Tags: excel, vba

It's not simple to get the values, don't know where to start to write a code

I added a picture with markings that will make it possible to explain the situation

[image: sample of worksheet]

so here I tell what I trying

the timevalues of red column with red arrow has to be in range al "hh:mm:ss"
but has also to stay in the original column as short date visible full value of original cel contains "dd:mm:yyyy hh:mm:ss" value also the first line in the filtered range rows"15:80015" must be skipped

second is the same of gray  column with gray arrow has to be in am "hh:mm:ss"
but here the first cell has not to be skipped so that i can sum al-am timevalues and see when it has a difference of more than 10minutes

hope this helps to write code or is there a easy way to do this. that column S cell value +1 row sums column t cell value and put the value in range al am or an

when use column t is hidden, but now i put it visible to explain 
so this must work when column t is hidden

code that i have for the moment is this

```
Private Sub CheckBox7_Click()
    Call man
    Dim rng As Range, cll As Range, i As Integer, al(80015) As Variant
    'Dim i As Long
    Dim cll2 As Range
    Dim i2 As Long
    'Dim lijnen As Range
    'Dim lijnen2 As Range
    Dim lijnen As String
    Dim lijnen2 As String
    Dim lstijd As String
    Dim lstijd2 As String
    Dim lstot As String
    Dim lslijn As String
    lijnen = "t15:t" & Range("t15").End(xlDown).Row
    lijnen2 = "s16:s" & Range("s16").End(xlDown).Row


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each cll In Range(lijnen).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If cll.Value <> "" Then
            For Each cll2 In Range(lijnen2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                lstijd = Range("s" & cll.Row + cll2.Row - cll.Row)
                Range("am" & cll.Row) = cll.Value
                Range("al" & cll.Row) = lstijd
            Next
        End If
    Next

    lstijd = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Call oto

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood this website. Because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Comment: added my code that i have for the moment

Comment: How are the time/date stamps added to your sheet? Are they added only to the columns on the left (indicated by your red and grey arrows) or does a separate sub apply the time/date values? What does `man` and `oto` do at the start and end of your `Sub`? Did you want to sum the time values with code and write it somewhere to your sheet or return a value as part of this/another sub? It might make things a bit easier to understand what you want where if you edit your image to include some references to row/column references and adjust your question to reflect these rather than drawings.